# What's wrong with this Logstash config?

Tags: amazon-s3, logstash, apache-kafka

We're using Logstash (2.3.3) to listen to multiple topics in Kafka, using Kafka's [new plugin (3.0.2)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-inputs-kafka.html). Data for each topic is then re-directed to specific folders in an S3 bucket based on the topic name (added as metadata). However, with the current config, data for only the first S3 output seems to be landing in its S3 bucket/folder.

Can someone let me know what's going wrong here? I'm pretty sure there's a better way of writing this config that can serve our requirement!

```
input
{
 kafka
 {
  bootstrap_servers => "10.0.0.5:9093,10.0.1.5:9093"
  topics => "topic"
  codec => "json"
  ssl => true
  ssl_keystore_location => "/opt/logstash/ssl/server.keystore.jks"
  ssl_keystore_password => "<snipped>"
  ssl_truststore_location => "/opt/logstash/ssl/server.truststore.jks"
  ssl_truststore_password => "<snipped>"
  add_field => { "[@metadata][topic]" => "topic" }
 }
 kafka
 {
  bootstrap_servers => "10.0.0.5:9093,10.0.1.5:9093"
  topics => "topic-test"
  codec => "json"
  ssl => true
  ssl_keystore_location => "/opt/logstash/ssl/server.keystore.jks"
  ssl_keystore_password => "<snipped>"
  ssl_truststore_location => "/opt/logstash/ssl/server.truststore.jks"
  ssl_truststore_password => "<snipped>"
  add_field => { "[@metadata][topic]" => "topic-test" }
 }
 kafka
 {
  bootstrap_servers => "10.0.0.5:9093,10.0.1.5:9093"
  topics => "daily_batch"  
  ssl => true
  ssl_keystore_location => "/opt/logstash/ssl/server.keystore.jks"
  ssl_keystore_password => "<snipped>"
  ssl_truststore_location => "/opt/logstash/ssl/server.truststore.jks"
  ssl_truststore_password => "<snipped>"
  add_field => { "[@metadata][topic]" => "daily_batch" }
 }
}

output
{
 if [@metadata][topic] == "topic"
 {
  s3
    {
     region => "us-east-1"
     bucket => "our-s3-storage/topic"
     size_file => 20971520
     temporary_directory => "/logstash"
     use_ssl => "true"
     codec => json_lines     
    }
 }
 if [@metadata][topic] == "topic-test"
 {
  s3
    {
     region => "us-east-1"
     bucket => "our-s3-storage/topic-test"
     size_file => 2097152
     temporary_directory => "/logstash"
     use_ssl => "true"
     codec => json_lines     
    }
 }
 if [@metadata][topic] == "daily_batch"
 {
  s3
    {
     region => "us-east-1"
     bucket => "our-s3-storage/daily_batch"
     size_file => 41943
     temporary_directory => "/logstash"
     use_ssl => "true"
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Unless you are using logstash `5.0`, currently in alpha, `topics` is not a valid option, you may want to use the current documentation instead: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-topics

Comment: I'm using the new Kafka input plugin with Logstash 2.3.3.

Comment: could you link to that?

Answer (score 0):

In Logstash `5.0` you'll be able to use `topics` and give an array of topics to your kafka input and have

```
topics => ["topic", "topic-test", "daily_batch"]
```

in one kafka input. However, this cannot be done with logstash 2.3, which does not have the `topics` field.

You can definitely condense your outputs by using logstash's ability to insert field values into strings in the config on a per-event basis. To make sure your data doesn't get weird one-off buckets on bad data you can use an array checking if.

```
if [@metadata][topic] in ["topic", "topic-test", "daily_batch"]
 {
  s3
    {
     region => "us-east-1"
     bucket => "our-s3-storage/%{[@metadata][topic]}"
     size_file => 41943
     temporary_directory => "/logstash"
     use_ssl => "true"
    }
 }
}
```